# how to configure unauthorized endpoint in Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Assume that I have the server started on http://localhost:8080/

How can I configure in order to skip authorization on http://localhost:8080/aaaa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/aaaa").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```